# Capitalisation: »auf etwas real existierendes/Existierendes«?

Tags: capitalization

I am unsure about a capitalisation in the following sentence:

»In diesem Sinne werden Fakten nicht nur als etwas verstanden, das auf etwas real existierendes referiert, sondern auch als etwas, das präsentiert wird, als ob es objektiv real ist.«

Does the word »existierendes« after »auf etwas real« have to be capitalised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Yes.

German requires all substantives to be capitalised.

Additionally, and in particular, all adjectives and participial verb forms *formally used* as substantives have to be capitalised. These formal substantive usages can normally be recognised by some simple tests - by checking for word combinations that can normally only be used with substantives:

1. The word in question comes along with an article that directly relates to it (*das Existierende*)
2. The word comes along with a pronoun (*dieser, jener, welcher, mein, kein, **etwas**, nichts, alle, einige ...*) also, directly relating to it (*etwas Existierendes*)
3. The word is paired with an indefinite numerical qualifier (*ein paar, genug, viel, wenig ...*)
4. It has an adjective attribute attached to it

That rule is stated as a general rule, with some exceptions - Your example is not one of these.